# Cannot add a custom CloudWatch log group to an AWS CDK DockerImageFunction() created Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

Using AWS CDK (2.66.0), when trying to add the property as `log_group=self.lambda_log_group` to the Lambda resource `ec2_launch_fn = DockerImageFunction()`, I get error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'log_group'.
```

I'm using AWS CDK version 2.66.0; also tried 2.133.0 with no luck.

Basically, I am trying to change a functional AWS Lambda to send its logs to a custom CloudWatch (CW) log group instead of sending its logs to an automatically created CW log group.

The Lambda resource `ec2_launch_fn = DockerImageFunction()` had a property `log_retention=logs.RetentionDays.ONE_MONTH` only, and it was sending its logs to an automatically created CW log group.

To change that, I created a CW log group resource `self.lambda_log_group = logs.LogGroup()` inside `def __init__()` and added the property `log_group=self.lambda_log_group` to the Lambda resource `ec2_launch_fn`. I also removed `log_retention=logs.RetentionDays.ONE_MONTH` from the Lambda resource.

The log group is created correctly, but the resource `log_group=self.lambda_log_group` is giving error as mentioned above. According to this [API Reference/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/DockerImageFunction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/DockerImageFunction.html), `log_group` is a valid property of `classaws_cdk.aws_lambda.DockerImageFunction()` in AWS CDK Python.

If I do not add this property `log_group=self.lambda_log_group` to the Lambda resource `ec2_launch_fn`, I get NO error, but the Lambda continues to send it's logs to the automatically created log group.

How can I fix this error and make the Lambda to send the custom CW log group?

AWS CDK code (removed some irreverent lines):

```
import os

from aws_cdk import (
    Duration,
    RemovalPolicy,
    Stack,
    aws_events as events,
    aws_events_targets as targets,
    aws_iam as iam,
    aws_ec2 as ec2,
    aws_ecr_assets as ecra,
    aws_logs as logs
)
from aws_cdk.aws_secretsmanager import Secret
from aws_cdk.aws_lambda import DockerImageCode, DockerImageFunction
from constructs import Construct


class AutoScalingLaunchLambdaCdkStack(Stack):
    # CDK stack to create lambda functions to process the ec2 launch hook event from auto-scaling groups

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, res_name: str, instance: str, config: list, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
        self._res_name = res_name
        self._instance = instance

        self.lambda_log_group = logs.LogGroup(
            self, f'{self._res_name}-EC2LifeCycleLaunchLogGroup-{self._instance}',
            log_group_name=f'/aws/lambda/EC2LifeCycleLaunch-{self._instance}-log',
            retention=logs.RetentionDays.ONE_MONTH,
            removal_policy=RemovalPolicy.DESTROY  # log group will be deleted from CW when the resource is removed from the code or the CFN stack is deleted
        )

        ec2_launch_fn: DockerImageFunction = self.build_auto_scaling_ec2_launch_lambda(config)
        self.set_role(ec2_launch_fn)

    def build_auto_scaling_ec2_launch_lambda(self, config: list) -> DockerImageFunction:
        stack_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        lambda_path = os.path.join(stack_path, "..", "lambdas", "auto_scaling_ec2_launch")

        auto_scaling_vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(
            self, "VPC", vpc_id=config["vpc_id"]
        )
        security_group = ec2.SecurityGroup(
            self,
            "{}-SecurityGroup-{}".format(self._res_name, self._instance),
            description=f"SecurityGroup for {self._res_name} - {self._instance}",
            vpc=auto_scaling_vpc,
            allow_all_outbound=True,
        )

        ec2_launch_fn = DockerImageFunction(
            self,
            "{}-EC2LifeCycleLaunch-{}".format(self._res_name, self._instance),
            function_name=f'EC2LifeCycleLaunch-{self._instance}',
            code=DockerImageCode.from_image_asset(
                directory=lambda_path,
                network_mode=ecra.NetworkMode.HOST
            ),
            description="Lambda to update Oracle database when an auto scaling group launches an EC2",
            environment={
                "REGION": self.region,
                "SECRET_NAME": f"{self._instance}/db/gbcust",
                "FO_ENVIRONMENT": self._instance,
            },
            vpc=auto_scaling_vpc,
            vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED),
            security_groups=[security_group],
            log_group=self.lambda_log_group,
            memory_size=128,
            timeout=Duration.seconds(30),
            retry_attempts=2
        )

        return ec2_launch_fn

    def set_role(self, ec2_launch_fn: DockerImageFunction):
        ec2_launch_fn.role.add_managed_policy(iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name("AmazonVPCFullAccess"))
        
        ec2_launch_fn.add_to_role_policy(
            iam.PolicyStatement(
                effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
                actions=["autoscaling:CompleteLifecycleAction"],
                resources=[
                    f"arn:aws:autoscaling:{self.region}:{self.account}:autoScalingGroup:*:autoScalingGroupName/*"]
            )
        )

        ec2_launch_fn.add_to_role_policy(
            iam.PolicyStatement(
                effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
                actions=["autoscaling:DescribeTags"],
                resources=["*"]
            )
        )

        ec2_launch_fn.add_to_role_policy(
            iam.PolicyStatement(
                effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
                actions=["autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingInstances"],
                resources=["*"]
            )
        )

        ec2_launch_fn.add_to_role_policy(
            iam.PolicyStatement(
                effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
                actions=["logs:CreateLogStream", "logs:PutLogEvents"],
                resources=[f"arn:aws:logs:{self.region}:{self.account}:log-group:{self.lambda_log_group.log_group_name}:*"]
            )
        )
```

Error from the pipeline:

```
17:51:35  + cdk deploy --force LifeCycleLaunchStack-dev --require-approval=never -c environment=dev -c service=fo-lifecycle
17:51:42  Traceback (most recent call last):
17:51:42    File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/_poc_environment_feature_ABC-888/app.py", line 53, in <module>
17:51:42      AutoScalingLaunchLambdaCdkStack(
17:51:42    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/jsii/_runtime.py", line 111, in __call__
17:51:42      inst = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
17:51:42    File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/_poc_environment_feature_ABC-888/build/stacks/lifecycle_launch_stack.py", line 38, in __init__
17:51:42      ec2_launch_fn: DockerImageFunction = self.build_auto_scaling_ec2_launch_lambda(config)
17:51:42    File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/_poc_environment_feature_ABC-888/build/stacks/lifecycle_launch_stack.py", line 62, in build_auto_scaling_ec2_launch_lambda
17:51:42      ec2_launch_fn = DockerImageFunction(
17:51:42    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/jsii/_runtime.py", line 111, in __call__
17:51:42      inst = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
17:51:42  TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'log_group'
```

Comment: Are you sure you're updating your library and not the CLI? What's the output of `pip freeze`?